# How to create Spot Light Effect in cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I am creating a game in cocos2d-x and want to create spotlight effect in it on my character. Is there any way to do it without using OpenGl? if not how can i do it with openGL?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check This out : in cocosx- 3.3 version they have already provided SpotLight Class .

**http://jonimikkola.com/2014/11/creating-light-spot-shader-in-cocos2d-x-3-0/
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.3rc0/df/d72/classcocos2d_1_1_spot_light.html**

Answer (score 1):

check this                         -
http://www.supersuraccoon-cocos2d.com/2011/09/09/spot-light-demo/

Comment: Is it available for cocos2d-x? I am converting the code myself right now. If it is, it would be a great help. Thanks

Comment: it is easy to convert otherwise you have to use cocos2dx 3.3 . if you have any problem in converting then let me know i can help you to convert . sorry for late responding .   Enjoy coding Enjoy Life